# Azure Function - Suspend queue trigger

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-queues

I have azure function with queue trigger and I wanna perform deploy of new version, but before that I need to be sure that function will finish ongoing executions. Does disabling specific functions (or stopping whole function) will interrupt current executions? If yes, is there any other way to suspend new executions and allow finish current one? And is there any metric which will show me ongoing execution count?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean stop running a few minutes, and then keep running from the point stopped. The answer is **No**.

Actually, you **can't** suspend the queue trigger functions, because the **queue message already consumed and deleted** after triggering, whether the whole function execute or not.

Even use **staging slot** swapping, the function would **not** be interrupted, but would be **running still**, which is **not** suspend the queue trigger, either.